# web service deployment does not appear in weblogic admin console

Tags: weblogic

We have an ear project created with Netbeans 8.1 and the Maven Project wizard. Running WLS 12.1.3. The project contains some EJBs and a jax-ws web service using the standard jax-ws annotations.  For some reason, I cannot get the web service to show up after deployment in the admin console as shown below.
[image]
However, the web service is deployed, and running properly, but then we cannot admin the deployment config, or monitor, etc.  The strange thing is that the corrsponding
servlet does show up on the testing tab.  Does anyone know what would cause this? [image]

Answer (score 0):

The web service should be running withing a `Web Application`.  I presume you have packaged the web service within a `war` file within the `ear`.  The web application specification will contain the context root.  Depending on your servlet mapping, or more paths within the context root will be handled by your web service.

Comment: Yes, to all the above.